# WordPress rowactions for WP_List_Table ColSpan

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using the WP_List_Table for displaying my data for my plugin and have rowactions tied to the first column (as show in multiple tutorials).  I have approximately 9 columns in my table and would like for the actions row to span across all of the columns (or at least more than one) in the table so that when the browser is resized, the actions aren't wrapped in a single cell.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: With [some very heavy weight jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13662815/1287812)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So I figure this is why WordPress doesn't support developers wanting to use WP_List_Table.  I'll think about going another route one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the function called single_row()  and write your row  with colspan.

ie, Define this function in your child class which extends WP_List_Table.

```
public function single_row( $item ) {
        static $row_class = '';
        $row_class = ( $row_class == '' ? ' class="alternate"' : '' );

        echo '<tr' . $row_class . '>';
        $this->single_row_columns( $item );
        echo '</tr>';

        // You can add a new row here with custom styles and attributes or edit the above one.
    }
```